# what is different between summary report and aggregate report?

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter load testing, what is the difference between summary report and aggregate report? Which one is the best?

And why in aggregate report 90%,95%,99% is given?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not much difference in fact:

- Summary Report has:

  - [Standard Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)
  - Average Bytes
- Aggregate Report has:

  - Median (50% line), 90, 95 and 99 percentiles.

Given you're new to JMeter I would recommend the following:

1. Once you finish developing your test, run it with 1-2 users using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and ensure that it does exactly what you expect
2. Disable **all listeners**. They cause overhead on JMeter side consuming lots of resources which may be required to create the load.
3. Run JMeter test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/test.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
   ```
4. Once test finishes open JMeter GUI, add listener(s) you need - you can add any listener you like at this stage and perform results analysis.

P.S. Some people find custom listeners provided by [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/) project easier to understand and interpret.

Comment: How does it matter if we enable/disable the listeners when running the jmeter via command-line non-GUI mode?

Comment: A listener is being executed after each Sampler (or according to the [scoping rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)) and contains all the context, including response data and variables. There is no sense in having Listeners because you can get all the information from the .jtl results file after test finishes.  More information [Greedy Listeners - Memory Leeches of Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/)

Comment: Ok I understand there is no sense in having listeners. But does it affect the non gui command line test in any way? For example: 1) does it collect more data based on listeners? 2) does the test use more cpu than it would have if there were no listeners? Or does the test disable the listeners automatically if test is run in command line non gui mode?

Comment: 1. Theoretically you can configure the listener to collect more data (like full response data), however you can achieve the same by manipulating [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) responsible for the [results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config). 2. Listeners have direct and huge impact on CPU, RAM and Disk IO. 3. JMeter doesn't automatically disable listeners in non-GUI mode

Answer (score 4):

They are almost same except that Aggregate report gives the median,90% line etc.
Due to that Aggregate report consumes more memory & summary reports takes less memory!!

Check here for more details

1. [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report)
2. [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report)

> Calculation of the Median and 90% Line (90th percentile) values
>   requires additional memory. JMeter now combines samples with the same
>   elapsed time, so far less memory is used. However, for samples that
>   take more than a few seconds, the probability is that fewer samples
>   will have identical times, in which case more memory will be needed.
>   Note you can use this listener afterwards to reload a CSV or XML
>   results file which is the recommended way to avoid performance
>   impacts. See the Summary Report for a similar Listener that does not
>   store individual samples and so needs constant memory.

**Median / 90% / 95% lines:**

- Median - The median is the time in the middle of a set of results. 50% of the samples took no more than this time; the remainder took at least as long. Median is another name of 50% line.
- 90% Line - 90% of the samples took no more than this time. The remaining samples took at least as long as this. (90th percentile)
- 95% Line - 95% of the samples took no more than this time. The remaining samples took at least as long as this. (95th percentile)

---

Actually you should be running your test in non-GUI mode w/o any listener. Once the test is done, You can import the jtl in any listener you want to see the results!!